# Static files in django 1.5 - working locally, not working on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, hosting, django-staticfiles

I have a project in Django 1.5 and hosts it on Heroku.
The problem is that I do not see the server static files (CSS, JS) (on the user and administrator) - went through the tutorial available at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
but nothing helps.

When I start the application locally using python manage.py runserver - everything works. Below is the code from the file setting.py

```
    import dj_database_url

    # Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    import os
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = False

    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'app',
    )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog_project.urls'

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog_project.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your setting for Heroku so that you include

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static'),
)
```

Its using a different lookup to

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: This solved the problem: from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application()) 

Thanks